# Modify array elements efficiently in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a python script that gives me an array as an output like so:

```
['1.1.1.1-1.1.1.5','2.2.2.2-2.2.3.3','5.5.5.5-5.5.5.5','6.6.1.2-6.6.1.7']
```

These are IP address ranges. The third element of this array however is not a range. How do I parse the array to find such elements and replace them with just a single IP?

Eg: '5.5.5.5-5.5.5.5' should be replaced with just '5.5.5.5'

I have one way of doing it. But I'm not sure if it's entirely efficient. I'm looking to see if there are better ways of doing it.

```
let ipRangeArray = ['1.1.1.1-1.1.1.5','2.2.2.2-2.2.3.3','5.5.5.5-5.5.5.5','6.6.1.2-6.6.1.7']

for (const [index, value] of ipRangeArray.entries()) {
  let splitArray = value.split('-'); //splitArray = ['5.5.5.5','5.5.5.5']
  splitArray[0] == splitArray[1] && (ipRangeArray[index] = splitArray[0])
} 

console.log(ipRangeArray); // ["1.1.1.1-1.1.1.5", "2.2.2.2-2.2.3.3", "5.5.5.5", "6.6.1.2-6.6.1.7"]
```

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that's particularly inefficient? It's not very *readable*, relying on side effects of evaluation for assignment is frankly horrible, but it's reasonably efficient.

Comment: My input array might grow in size and I somehow feel that this might slow down with longer arrays since we look at each element sequentially. I'm more concerned with time than memory usage.

Comment: Well it's `O(n)`, so... yes, I'd expect it to get slower as the array gets longer, but how could you possibly do better than that? Unless you know which items you will consider "not a range" by index in advance, or how many non-ranges there are, or some other information that you can optimise on, you *must* look at each one sequentially.

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe . Also, unless you have a reliable benchmark that proves otherwise, this is extremely unlikely to be a bottleneck.

Comment: This is offtopic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and compare the elements.

```js
var array = ['1.1.1.1-1.1.1.5', '2.2.2.2-2.2.3.3', '5.5.5.5-5.5.5.5', '6.6.1.2-6.6.1.7'],
    clean = array.map(s => (([l, r]) => l === r ? l : s)(s.split('-')));
    
console.log(clean);
```

Comment: That's what their code *already does*... You're creating a new array instead of mutating the old one, but the core logic is identical.

Comment: ... *"how do I make it more efficient?"*